# UnknownTags,[] imfinfo Fields

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to ask about some info concerning the images I used In my work,I have two images and I denoised them by using the same code. the problem is that one of them is effected in the grayscale I'm not sure about the reason why but when I get the informations concerning them I get :

```
for the first Image :

    XResolution: []
    YResolution: []

for the second image :

    XResolution: 985.7284
    YResolution: 985.7284
    UnknownTags: [2x1 struct]
```

Is there any one knows what does the accolades mean [] ?, and UnknownTags what does it mean?and if I can change the resolution to [] ;might this give me the required result.

after I did the thresholding the image become a binary image knowing that my image is a grayscale image 32 bits I'm trying to find some solution. how can I return it to its origine grayscale 32bit

Comment: [] is an empty structure. E.g. a 1x1 cellarray. I have no idea how these are constructed. You should post some of your code (e.g. where you define those values and your noise reduction) so that others can see what you are doing.

Comment: it's not matter of what I did Mr.The Minion . it's about the characteristics of these images and if I can change the resolution of an image XREsolution=[]?????? what does it mean?